# Class object will not push_back onto vector

Tags: c++, class, object, vector

Compiles and everything except adding in a 'ship'

Constructor for ship

```
Ship::Ship(std::string name, int length, std::string show) {

    std::string _name = name;
    int _length = length;
    std::string _show = show;
}    

void Ships::buildShip() {
        std::string name, show;
        int length = 0;
        std::cout << "What is the name of the ship?  ";
        std::cin >> name;

        std::cout << "How long is the ship in feet?  ";
        std::cin >> length;

        std::cout << "What show/movie is the ship from?  ";
        std::cin >> show;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        Ship ship(name, length, show);
        addShip(ship);
}


void Ships::addShip(Ship &ship) {
    ships.push_back(ship);
}
```

I'm sure it's something very obvious, I've searched the web and found nothing helpful. I only took snippets from my code if anything else is needed let me know. Thanks in advance!

```
    /Ship.h
#pragma once
#include <string>

class Ship {
    std::string _name;
    int _length;
    std::string _show;

public:
    Ship(){
        std::string name = _name;
        int length = _length;
        std::string show = _show;
    };
    Ship(std::string _name, int _length, std::string _show);
    std::string getName();
    int getLength();
    std::string getShow();

};

    /Ship.cpp
#include <string>
#include "Ship.h"

Ship::Ship(std::string name, int length, std::string show) {

    std::string _name = name;
    int _length = length;
    std::string _show = show;
}

std::string Ship::getName() {
    return _name;
}

int Ship::getLength() {
    return _length;
}

std::string Ship::getShow() {
    return _show;
}

    /Ships.h
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "Ship.h"

class Ships {
    std::vector<Ship> ships;
public:
    void addShip(Ship &ship);
    int getCount();
    Ship getLongestShip();
    void buildShip();
    int getNumberOfShipsLongerThan(int input);
    void displayShips();
};

    /Ships.cpp
#include "Ships.h"
#include <iostream>

void Ships::addShip(Ship &ship) {
    ships.push_back(ship);
}


int Ships::getCount() {
    return ships.size();
}

Ship Ships::getLongestShip() {
    Ship longestShip = ships[0];
    for (Ship aShip : ships) {
        if (longestShip.getLength() < aShip.getLength())
            longestShip = aShip;
    }
    std::cout << "The longest ship is the " << longestShip.getName() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "From end to end the length is " << longestShip.getLength() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The show/movie it is from is " << longestShip.getShow() << std::endl;
    return longestShip;
}

int Ships::getNumberOfShipsLongerThan(int input) {
    int longerThan = 0;
    int size = ships.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (input < ships[i].getLength())
            longerThan++;
    }
    return longerThan;
}

void Ships::displayShips() {
    std::cout << " Complete Bay Manifest " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "***********************" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < ships.size(); i++) {
        int a = i + 1;
        std::cout << "Ship (" << a << ")" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Name: " << ships[i].getName() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Length: " << ships[i].getLength() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Show: " << ships[i].getShow() << std::endl<<std::endl;
    }
}

void Ships::buildShip() {
        std::string name, show;
        int length = 0;
        std::cout << "What is the name of the ship?  ";
        std::cin >> name;

        std::cout << "How long is the ship in feet?  ";
        std::cin >> length;

        std::cout << "What show/movie is the ship from?  ";
        std::cin >> show;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        Ship ship(name, length, show);
        addShip(ship);
}

    /driver.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Ship.h"
#include "Ships.h"

void menu();
Ship buildShip();
void shipsInBay(Ships &ships);
void processDirective(int choice, Ships &ships);
void longerThan(Ships &ships);

int main() {
    std::cout << "Welcome to Daniel Mikos' Ship Bay!" << std::endl << std::endl;
    menu();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void menu() {
    Ships ships;
    int choice = 0;
        std::cout << "Please make a selection" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " (1) Add a ship to the bay" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " (2) How many ships are already in the bay?" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " (3) Which ship is the longest? " << std::endl;
        std::cout << " (4) Ships longer than ___? " << std::endl;
        std::cout << " (5) Manifest of all ships currently logged" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " (6) Exit" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " Choice: ";
        std::cin >> choice;
        processDirective(choice, ships);
}

Ship buildShip() {
    std::string name, show;
    int length = 0;
    std::cout << "What is the name of the ship?  ";
    std::cin >> name;

    std::cout << "How long is the ship in feet?  ";
    std::cin >> length;

    std::cout << "What show/movie is the ship from?  ";
    std::cin >> show;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    Ship ship(name, length, show);
    return ship;
}

void shipsInBay(Ships &ships) {
    int count = ships.getCount();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "There is currently " << count;
    std::cout << " ship(s) in bay" << std::endl << std::endl;
}

void longerThan(Ships &ships) {
    int input = 0;
    std::cout << "Find ships longer than? ";
    std::cin >> input;
    std::cout << "There are " << ships.getNumberOfShipsLongerThan(input) << "longer than " << input << "feet";
}

void processDirective(int choice, Ships &ships) {
    if (choice == 1)
        buildShip();
    if (choice == 2)
        shipsInBay(ships);
    if (choice == 3)
        ships.getLongestShip();
    if (choice == 4)
        longerThan(ships);
    if (choice == 5)
        ships.displayShips();
    menu();
}
```

There is all of my code

Comment: How do you know it isn't adding it to the vector? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Tried to add a screen capture but I have a ships.size(); (ships being my vector) after I add one I run the size and it comes up as 0. I had it running before and it would say 1 buuut when I would try and display it, the name and show would be blank while length would be -803254

Comment: Your constructor looks wrong. Why are you creating new local variables  `_name`, `_length`  and `_show` instead of initializing class members?

Comment: @Mikos without a [mcve] that we can run ourselves we don't know how you're determining that your code isn't working. That said, drescherjm is correct that the constructor for `Ship` is wrong. You're creating local variables for what I can only assume should be data members.

Comment: Ships is supposed to be a 'wrapper' class. The constructor is like that so I can access the private members of Ship

Comment: ***The constructor is like that so I can access the private members of Ship*** It's implemented wrongly as I described. You are not accessing any members of `Ship` in your constructor. You are creating new local variables with the same name as ones in the Ship class. When you include the type in your assignments you create a declaration of a new variable in the current scope masking the variable of the same name in the outer scope.

Comment: We do not need all of your code.  we need a [mcve] and we need to know how the code does not work

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry man, I tried to be minimal with my first post, obviously wasn't enough code. Now I've done too much code. Will do my best to find the sweet middle ground next post!

Comment: In this case  all you needed for a minimal case was the constructor and the header and Ships::buildShip. Again the bug is in the constructor.

Comment: Change the implementation of `Ship()` to  Ship() : _length(0) {} or Ship() : _length {} {} if you use c++11.

Answer (score 0):

To add an object to a vector of objects use `emplace_back()` and pass the constructor arguments as arguments to emplace back. It will then build the object in place so call:

```
ships.emplace_back(name, length, show);
```

to construct your ship object in place. Your constructor also is incorrect as pointed out by @Kevin. You need to change it to:

```
this->_name = name;
this->_length = length;
this->_show = show;
```

assuming I've guessed your class design correctly.

**EDIT**

Tried to build a minimum example from this and this works fine for me:

`Header.h`

```
class Ship {
    std::string _name;
    int _length;
    std::string _show;

public:
    Ship();
    Ship(std::string _name, int _length, std::string _show);
    std::string getName();
    int getLength();
    std::string getShow();

};

class Ships {
public:

    void addShip(Ship &ship);
    void buildShip();

    std::vector<Ship> ships;
};
```

and `Source.cpp`

```
#include "Header.h"

Ship::Ship(std::string name, int length, std::string show) {

    this->_name = name;
    this->_length = length;
    this->_show = show;
}

void Ships::buildShip() {
std::string name = "Name";
std::string show = "Show";
int length = 0;
ships.emplace_back(name, length, show);
}


int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
    Ships ships;
    ships.buildShip();

    std::cout << "Number of ships = " << ships.ships.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Prints `Number of ships = 1`. Can you slim it down to something like this?

Comment: This is unrelated to the problem. `Ship ship(...); ships.push_back(ship);` should be equivalent to `ships.emplace_back(...);`. Also the initializer list should be used instead of `this->__ = __;`.

Comment: Good advice but this doesn't solve the problem.  We need the OP to provide a mcve to give a real answer

Comment: Fair comments, I've just seen the rest of the code posted a moment ago so will take a look again.

Comment: @CodingLumis Thank you for your help, I've made all the changes as you've written above. Still is not working correctly...I'll keep trying

Comment: ***Still is not working correctly*** I advise you to learn to step through code with your debugger line by line. That way you can see the exact point that your code does not operate like you expect.